# Completely hide passwords from log in InstallShield

Tags: security, logging, windows-installer, installshield

I am creating an installer, which executes a number of .msi packages. To prevent passwords from showing up in the log, I have taken af series of actions:

**Added password properties to MsiHiddenProperties**

Shows

```
InstallShield: Deferred property my_secret_password="MyPassword"
```

as

```
InstallShield: Deferred property my_secret_password="********"
```

**Added custom action name to MsiHiddenProperties**

Shows

```
Property(S): MyCustomAction = SUPPORTDIR="C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF}" MY_SECRET_PASSWORD="MyPassword"
```

as

```
Property(S): MyCustomAction = **********
```

**Added *IS_CHAINER_POST_COMMANDLINE* to MsiHiddenProperties**

Same as above, this property lists the full command line for invoking all .msi packages, including the propagated properties in clear text.

**Masked custom action types with 0x2000 in Direct Editor**

Shows

```
Action 12:34:56: MyCustomAction. 
MSI (s) (04:14) [12:34:56:789]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=MyCustomAction,ActionType=3073,Source=BinaryData,Target=m14,CustomActionData=SUPPORTDIR="C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF}" SQL_DATABASE_INSTANCE="localhost\sqlexpress" MY_SECRET_PASSWORD="MyPassword")
```

as

```
Action 12:34:56: MyCustomAction. 
MSI (s) (04:14) [12:34:56:789]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=MyCustomAction,ActionType=11265,Source=BinaryData,Target=********,CustomActionData=********)
```

---

### The problem

The passwords are still written as clear text in the log files on one occation:

**When properties are propagated from the main installer to the .msi packages**

```
Action 12:34:56: ISChainPackagePrepare. 
Action start 12:34:56: ISChainPackagePrepare.
MSI (s) (54:50) [12:34:56:789]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI1234.tmp, Entrypoint: ISChainPackages
InstallShield 12:34:56: Marking chained package Pkg1 for installation
InstallShield 12:34:56: Properties: "INSTALLDIR=\"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProductName\\\" MY_SECRET_PASSWD=\"MyPassword\""
```

### The question

How do I hide sensitive properties from being shown in the log when propagating them to other packages?

Comment: What version of InstallShield are you using? We've improved this piecemeal over the years, so I don't want to make suggestions that you can't use. (BTW, love the completeness of what you've done so far! It serves as a great how-to for others obscuring passwords.)

Comment: FWIW if you move this functionality out of the installer and into application first run or some other post install configuration process it really makes the installer a lot easier.

Comment: @MichaelUrman, my bad for not providing that, I am using InstallShield 2013 SP1, but an upgrade to the newest version is not out of sight, so if that will resolve this issue, that will be sufficient in my case. And thank you, I must give you some of the credit, as I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/38636195/4750010 as inspiration for some of the steps.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter, thank you, I have considered this approach, but currently it is preferred to use the built-in chaining feature, unless it proves impossible to obtain complete masking this way.